# 404 and 'Repository does not have a release file' on apt-get update for Ubuntu 18.04.5

Tags: 18.04, apt, updates

I'm trying to install a product on a client's server and am continuously hit with the following output when I try to run `apt-get update`:

```
root@cfmpoweredge:/etc/apt# apt-get update
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Ign:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Err:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Err:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

The `/etc/apt/sources.list` file looks like this:

```
root@cfmpoweredge:/etc/apt# cat sources.list
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main restricted
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic universe
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates universe
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
```

I've tried substituting `archive.ubuntu.com` for both `us.archive.ubuntu.com` and `za.archive.ubuntu.com` (we are based in South Africa) and am met with similar errors each time, as I am when using `mirrors.digitalocean.com`.

Furthermore, I'm able to ping both the URL and the IP address listed in the 404 messages, so I'm fairly certain it's not a network connectivity issue. There are no proxies specified in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You've checked already, I presume. But this looks like you are behind a proxy

Comment: @rm-rf I wish, that would make diagnosing the problem much easier. No, the server is connected directly to the internet.

Comment: Another thing what might set you on track: You'll also get 404's if your UB distro is out of the support time span.

Comment: We use Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS as it's [https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases](supported until April 2023), but the thought did certainly cross my mind. A lot of forum results suggest using old-releases.ubuntu.com as a repository, but as Bionic isn't yet out-of-life that isn't an option @rm-rf

Comment: I agree that it looks like it should be working: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/ ... I'm assuming you've tried again, in case the site was being "refreshed"?

Comment: @Jad Indeed; tried multiple times with multiple variations of the sources.list file, all to no avail

Comment: did the link, in my comment, work on the computer that's having trouble updating?  if you don't have a browser, you might need to `wget` or `curl` it

Comment: @Jad It did not, surprisingly! Even bad results are results. This would point to a potential networking issue then?

A little digging to (aka `curl http://archive.ubuntu.com`) gave me [this](https://pastebin.com/8yBaB7Uw), which is definitely not right. I'll ask the client to double check their network configuration

Comment: so not a proxy exactly, but there-in lies your problem.  good luck

Comment: @Jad Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst not strictly a proxy issue, the problem was indeed network related.

The server could connect by `ping`ing the repository mirrors, but `curl`ing the addresses returned a Mikrotik router login page. Upon further inspection, this seemed to be the case for *any* site. That'll teach me to use `ping` for testing network connectivity!

Thanks @rm-rf and @Jad for their assistance